# Update a boolean cell in my table

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a form and I want to update the `show_msg` parameter (it's a boolean parameter) while the user press the submit button. if the user checked the box and press submit, I want to set it TRUE. otherwise: FALSE.

so I have the main html that has a popup window. in this popup window I wrote my form. (**what should I have the write in 'action'?** I just have to close this popup window):

```
<form name="input" action="#" method="post">
   <input type="checkbox" id="mycheckbox">Don't show me again<br>
   <input type="submit" id="Submit">
</form>
```

this is my javascript:

```
$("#submit").click(function() {
   $.ajax({
     ## the url is the controller
     url: '/welcome',
     type: 'PUT',
     data: {show_msg: $("#mycheckbox").is(":checked")}
   });
});
```

and this is my controller:

```
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController

def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
        if @user.update_attributes(params[:show_msg])
            format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'You will never see this message again.' }
            format.json { head :no_content }
        end
    end
end
```

any help appreciated!

Comment: Add the id of the record to be updated in ajax url. I mean `url: '/welcome' + some_method_to_get_id`

Comment: I think it should get it automatically from the url (because it's a put request).

Comment: No.. The put request means that there should be an id associated somewhere in hidden field or passed as url_parameter. In rails, if you use the form helper then the object passed to it will do it magically. But in your case, you'll have to specify it explicitly. :)

Comment: I'm sorry but I am not sure if you are right. the ajax call the function of `update` in the controller of `Welcome`. in this function, I have: "@user = User.find(params[:id])", so it gets the id. am I wrong?

Comment: Ok. Try printing the params[:id] in your controller and see you are getting it. :)

Comment: @SybariteManoj, I think you are right. I'm sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Build the form with the Rails `form_for` tag.

Then instead of trigger an event on Submit button click, trigger on Form submit.

Finally, in you `$.ajax call`, for the `url` attribute, retrieve the good URL from the form action attribute.

For information, with the form tag, you can add a `remote: true` option. And then bind an event on `ajax:success`, `ajax:error` etc.

Answer (score 1):

Set the action to the URL of the server side process that will handle the submitted data if the JavaScript fails.

See also [Progressive Enhancement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement) and [Unobtrusive JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript).